# Visual studio code - terminal issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, utf-8, polish

I'm trying to solve the problem with running python files in vsc on Windows. When I do it with the arrow on the right side I got this output:

```
python -u "c:\Users\Uytkownik\Desktop\pyth\sss.py"
C:\Users\Użytkownik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\Uytkownik\\Desktop\\pyth\\sss.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It is caused by the fact that VSC skips polish letter "ż" (In the running command we can see Uytkownik instead of Użytkownik). I installed some language packs but it doesn't solve the problem with running. Is this any possibility to unable to type the letter "ż" in the terminal(type polish letters).

Comment: Why not modify your folder name? Many times using plain English paths will avoid a lot of trouble.

Comment: Work things, I'm not allowed to change it without having a password(Użytkownik is the name of the actual profile)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. What do you mean by _the arrow on the right side_? What's _right side_? And I can't se any _arrow_ in my `code` window.

Comment: This should refer to the play button in the upper right corner of the vscode interface (used to run or debug code).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)** extension to run your code. This may have caused some problems.

Please run the code using another **Run Python File** option under the play button, this will run the code using the **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)** extension.

[image]

Although on my machine both are fine. But for you, dropping **Code Runner** might solve the problem.

[image]

[image]